# AlertDialog not displaying in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` in android studio as shown below:

```
final EditText columninput = new EditText(this);
columninput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setTitle("Choose column number");
adb.setView(columninput);
adb.setMessage("Please specify the number of columns you would like to decrypt your message with.");
adb.setCancelable(true);
adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        boolean bool = true;

        try {
            col = Integer.parseInt(columninput.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            bool = false;
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }

        if (bool) {
             dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});

adb.show();

method1(toRead, col);
```

Note that `toRead` is another variable dealt with outside of this context; it should not be causing any errors. When I run my application, the `AlertDialog` is never shown, and `method1` runs immediately. However, when I comment out the last line (`method1(toRead, col)`), the alertdialog appears when the application is run. Why is this, and how can I ensure that the alertDialog is always shown?

Comment: well....then post the method1 please...

Comment: to find out, post the code of `method1()` also note that when showing dialog and you want to get a result from the dialog in order to use it in another method , ex `method1()` you can't do it this way, you need to use dialog positive button to either call either a callback in parent , or to call method1() itself.

Comment: I would post method1(), but it's very long (over 300 lines of code!). I've tested it out on its own however, and I'm fairly sure it should not be the source of any error...

Comment: ok, for now try to move the call to `method1(toRead, col);` inside `onClick()` of positive button, just below `col = ...`

Comment: Great! That seemed to work. It has, however, opened up a whole new slew of unrelated errors for me to debug. Oh well! That's coding...

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears because, when you open **AlertDialog**, the activity goes into pause state. 
So, when you hide the last line and don't call the method the activity is able to go into **Pause** state and the **AlertDialog** appears successfully.

While in the other case, when the last method is called, what happens is:

 before your **AlertDialog** gets created, the **method1()** gets called.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you:

**Example:**

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Delete")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete Product?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dbni.delete(ItemID);
                    arrayStudent = dbni.selectAll();
                    list_view.setAdapter(new Adapter_viewitem(mactivity, arrayStudent));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```